# Calling "unknown" function in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am currently building a react app to integrate with OneTrust.
In order to make the cookie table render dynamically, i have to call a function called `OneTrust.initializeCookiePolicyHtml()`

This comes from an external library and is known to the browser in the runtime. If however, I want to trigger this function from within react after mounting the component, typescript does now know how to handle this call and blocks the build.

I tried declaring Onetrust, but this only bubbles the problem further to the next property.

> declare function OneTrust(any: any): any;

> TS2339: Property 'initializeCookiePolicyHtml' does not exist on type '(any: any) => any'

My question here therefore is: how can I call a function that is only available through the runtime?

Thank you kindly!

Comment: If the type is `any` then you can call any function you like on it.  But according to the error the type is `(any: any) => any`, which is itself a function.  Maybe you need to invoke that function first?  Maybe there was a problem in how it was typed at declaration?  Where is this type information coming from?  Please provide more information about the code.

Comment: You're right! I was missing that snipped.
i declare onetrust as any like declare function OneTrust(any: any): any;

Comment: So `OneTrust` is a function?  Did you mean to call that function and then call `initializeCookiePolicyHtml()` on its result?

Comment: Yes exactly! THis is one of those "plug and play" libraries that you only drop in a script tag to make them work. Since the website is super dynamic with react, at runtime the target container is not present, so i need to make sure to initialize manually, once the container is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your runtime code, `OneTrust` should be `declare`d like this:

```
declare const OneTrust: {
    initializeCookiePolicyHtml: () => any;
};

OneTrust.initializeCookiePolicyHtml();
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?preserveWatchOutput=false&pretty=false#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3geRSAKjAK6YBc8A3gLABQ898Alioxo1BIwF4gDCSSANaMQABSScwATwASGALYRyACgCU8ALwA%20eFBRSA3LQC%20RmrVwFimAHTNW7Tj35CR4ybIUQ1BoA)

Comment: This works like a charm!
The project now compiles. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you know object name at runtime yout can with code like this:

```
class OneTrust {
    initializeCookiePolicyHtml() {
        console.log("called initializeCookiePolicyHtml()");
    }
}
let oneTrust = new OneTrust();
const methodName = "initializeCookiePolicyHtml";
oneTrust[methodName].apply(oneTrust);
```